# Keystone returning is_admin = 0 in every case

Tags: openstack, devstack, keystone

Did a search on this and found:

[Keystone returning token with metadata is_admin = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123625/keystone-returning-token-with-metadata-is-admin-0)

which doesn't really answer the question, and it's a year old, so I thought I'd open a new one.

I am running a VM instance of Ubuntu 14.04 running the latest build of devstack (as in less than a few weeks old) and am seeing strange behavior from keystone, I think.

I understand the admin role is supposed to be tenant specific, but my observations contradict that.

1) Keystone NEVER returns is_admin=1.  Authenticating to the admin tenant, with the admin user, who has the admin role for the admin tenant STILL returns "is_admin 0". Is there a guarantee that the admin role will always be named "admin"? If so, could you just use .user.roles.name = admin to check?

2) If that's true, I still need to provide a tenant when authenticating in order for that array to be populated in the response.  Why does this matter? Well I would like to authenticate without a tenant, get a list of tenants and roles, and then re-authenticate to a particular tenant to do something useful.  Why?  Because I don't want to have to know my list of tenants and roles ahead of time. I want to write an automated process that allows a login and upon authenticating, displays a list of tenants and additional functionality, IF and only IF the user is an admin.

3) Frustratingly, and this is a continuation of #2.  If the admin role is truly tenant specific, then  logging in using tenant A shouldn't allow me to do admin things on tenant B when I'm not even a member of tenant B, and it most certainly does.  This would lead me to believe the admin role is global, period.  It would make more sense to me, I would think to have tenant specific admins, admins that have access to a set of tenants, and global admins, but either this is not the case and they're lying or I am just completely bafffled by Openstack identity.

Since all internet searches have come up nada, or seem to assume that the reader already knows the context and answer to the question they are trying to address, can someone explain to me:

A) What IS the official prupose/limitations of the admin role?

B) Why on Earth doesn't my first point work?

C) Why does the admin role seem to be global?

D) Where is there documentation on this that doesn't assume you already know the intimate details of keystone?  E.g., The admin role is blah blah blah.  You configure its access here in blah blah blah.  It operates exactly this way: blah blah blah.  Not referencing or assuming any prior exposure to Openstack and all in one place?

E) Am I asking too much?  :)

Thanks.

Comment: Found this: http://www.florentflament.com/blog/customizing-openstack-rbac-policies.html and this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/keystone/+bug/968696

Comment: This was not an answer to my original question, by the way.  It does, however, answer point A & C.  Admin is always global, period.  There is a bug filed.  As of April, this has not been fixed.  I'd still like to know why is_admin is returning 0.

Comment: In my understanding , is_admin will be 1 only if the api's are executed using the service token i.e admin_token in keystone.conf